# Can I Exclude Movement Speeds When Wild Shaping?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

I am currently playing a level 2 Druid (Circle of the Land) in our game. Am I able to wild shape into a constrictor snake that does not have a swim speed in order to comply with the wild shape limitations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot exclude the movement speeds.  When you wild shape, you replace all game statistics of your character with those of the beast you shape into:

> **Your    game    statistics  are replaced    by  the statistics  of  the beast**,    but you retain  your    alignment,  personality,    and Intelligence,   Wisdom, and Charisma    scores. You also    retain  all of  your    skill    and    saving  throw   proficiencies,  in  addition    to  gaining those   of  the creature.   If  the creature    has the same    proficiency as  you and the bonus   in  its stat    block   is  higher  than    yours, use  the creature’s  bonus   instead of  yours.  If  the creature    has any legendary   or  lair    actions,    you can’t   use them.

Game statistics include movement speeds.  You can't take the movement speed out of the constrictor snake - at that point you're making a new beast, not using an existing one from the rules.  From a gameplay perspective that's probably fine, as I can't see any real balance reasons not to allow it, but it'd be a houserule to do so.

Keep in mind, however, that the limitation on swim and fly speed is in place not only to prevent you from gaining a swim/fly speed at an earlier level and and to make it feel like a reward later, but also to limit the list from which you can choose which animals to *wild shape* into, i.e., constrictor snake "unlocks" at druid level 4.

Comment: I thought that was likely the case, but wasn't sure if there had been any obscure Crawford clarification on it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## No, but ask your DM about "reskinning" a creature

You can't just *say* you're turning into a constrictor snake without a swim speed, but with all monster stats (and especially animal stats), the DM is encouraged to use them as a base to create other creatures; it's possible to use the stats for one type of large cat to represent another, for example, and the DM may be all right saying that there's another kind of snake out there in the game world that's very much like the constrictor snake but isn't as adept at swimming (there may be snakes like that in the real world too but that's a bit beyond me to say for sure).

Of course, *all* rules are subject to DM interpretation, but this one is particularly easy to tweak without major repercussions, so a lot of DMs are more cool with doing so.